# regex in as3 to ignore match with specific start to string

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have the following as3 function below which converts normal html with links so that the links have 'event:' prepended so that I can catch them with a TextEvent listener.

```
protected function convertLinks(str:String):String
{
  var p1:RegExp = /href|HREF="(.[^"]*)"/gs;
  str = str.replace(p1,'HREF="event:$1"');
  return str;
}
```

For example

```
<a href="http://www.somedomain.com">
```

gets converted to

```
<a href="event:http://www.somedomain.com">
```

This works just fine, but i have a problem with links that have already been converted.

I need to exclude the situation where i have a string such as

```
<a href="event:http://www.somedomain.com">
```

put through the function, because at the moment this gets converted to

```
<a href="event:event:http://www.somedomain.com">
```

Which breaks the link.

How can i modify my function so that links with 'event:' at the start are NOT matched and are left unchanged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, trying to manipulate HTML with regex may not be a good idea.

That said, according to the [flavor comparison chart on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), ActionScript regex is based off of ECMA engine, which supports [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Thus you can write this:

```
/(?:href|HREF)="(?!event:)(.[^"]*)"/
```

`(?=…)` is *positive* lookahead; it asserts that a given pattern can be matched. `(?!…)` is *negative* lookahead; it asserts that a given pattern can *NOT* be matched.

Note that the inclusion of the `.` is very peculiar. It's probably not intended to include the `.` there since it can match a closing doublequote.

Note also that I've fixed the [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for the `href/HREF` by using a non-capturing [*group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:…)`.

This is because:

- `this|that` matches either `"this"` or `"that"`
- `this|that thing` matches either `"this"` or `"that thing"`
- `(this|that) thing` matches either `"this thing"` or `"that thing"`

Alternatively you may also want to just turn on [case-insensity flag `/i`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), which would handle things like `hReF` or `eVeNt:`.

Thus, perhaps your pattern should just be

```
/href="(?!event:)([^"]*)"/gsi
```

If lookahead was not supported, you can use an [*optional*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) pattern that matches `event:` if it's there, excluding it from group 1, so that it doesn't get included when you substitute in `$1`.

```
/href="(?:event:)?([^"]*)"/gsi
       \________/ \_____/
   non-capturing    group 1
     optional
```

Comment: polygenelubricants, many thanks, your original line of code did exactly what i needed, as lookahead is supported.

Thank you also for the additonal information. RegEx seems to be a very specific way of thinking that i haven't quite got my head round yet. You really need to learn all the syntax properly, so thanks for your detail explanation.